# Understanding simple XText cross-referencing

Tags: dsl, xtext, cross-reference

I have a question regarding Xtext for Eclipse.

I have a simple example which I believe, follows very closely the examples given in online documentation and howtos (as for example: http://blog.efftinge.de/2012/05/implementing-fowlers-state-machine-dsl.html).

My grammar looks like the following:

```
MyModel : 
 properties += PropertyDefinition+
  rules += Rule+
;

PropertyDefinition :
 'property' name=ID '{'
   propertyValues += PropertyValue+
 '}'
;

PropertyValue :
 name=ID code=ID ';'
;

Rule :
 'rule:' value=[PropertyValue]
;
```

My problem is that the cross-reference in the rule "Rule" does not work. So my question is basically, what is the difference between my usage of cross-references and the one provided in the link above.

Their example works out of the box without custom scoping or similar. So I guess, so should mine.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Regardless of the exact problem, it's **always** a good idea to specify in more detail what *"it does not work"* means exactly for you.

Answer (score 2):

The PropertyValue is contained in a named element (PropertyDefinition) which by default will turn the name of a PropertyValue into a qualified name, i.e.

```
PropertDefintion.name+'.'+PropertyValue.name
```

If you want to refer to a qualified name, the cross reference needs to use a syntactic rule for that:

```
Rule : 'rule' value=[PropertyValue|QualifiedName]
```

If you do not want to use a qualified name you have to change the IQualifiedNameStrategy.
Simply bind a different implementation in your runtime module, e.g. :

```
public Class<? extends IQualifiedNameProvider> bindIQualifiedNameProvider() {
  return SimpleNameProvider.class;
}
```